# When I deploy in Azure web job in Azure app service it fails due to exit code -532462766

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

Even I have created a new web job and updated web job package with 2.0.0 and deployed on azure app service still same following error code.

> [12/29/2020 04:34:03 > 7bdc9c: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> [12/29/2020 04:34:03 > 7bdc9c: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.Start()
> [12/29/2020 04:34:03 > 7bdc9c: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.RunAndBlock()
> [12/29/2020 04:34:03 > 7bdc9c: ERR ]    at PartPay.Application.ScheduledTasks.Program.Main() in C:\Project\PayFlax2.0\src\PartPay.Application.ScheduledTasks\Program.cs:line 27
> [12/29/2020 04:34:03 > 7bdc9c: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766
> [12/29/2020 04:34:03 > 7bdc9c: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 0 seconds
> [12/29/2020 04:34:03 > 7bdc9c: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart
> [12/29/2020 04:34:03 > 7bdc9c: SYS INFO] Run script 'PartPay.Application.ScheduledTasks.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
> [12/29/2020 04:34:03 > 7bdc9c: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running

Comment: the issue is resolved its due to the vnet integration.we have moved out storage account into vnet and its started working

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have  web.config  file has necessary connections string.

Also, recommend you to revisit your code to see if there is any exceptions that may occur. You could introduce the try {} catch {} in your code to further understand.

The error code ideally is the  exception code used internally by the CLR to represent most exceptions.